# JAVA - ASM bytecode manipulation

Tags: java, obfuscation, bytecode

So I have some obfuscated code like this:

```
     public class a { 
         public void something(Object[] arrayOfObject, int var0, int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4, int var5, int var6, int var7, int var8) {...}
     }
```

I am trying to capture var6 and var7 so I can assign assign them to a field (PUTFIELD) using ASM but I'm having trouble. I have managed to successfully create two fields in a class using ASM, but I haven't managed to assign a value to those fields using the method.

Could someone show me how I could do this?

Comment: In that method, `var6` and `var7` correspond to `iload 8` and `iload 9`, so you'll want to first insert those, then load your `this` object with `aload_0`, followed by a `getfield` to get the necessary field, and finally an `istore` to store the field into the local variable.

Comment: If you're manipulating classes by hand, you're probably better off using a dedicated assembler, rather than ASM. ASM is useful for programmatic transformations, but it's really clunky when used manually.